# Can you use 'less' or 'more' to output one page worth of text?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

So in Linux, `less` is used to read files page by page for better readability. I was wondering if you can do something like `less file.txt > output.txt` to get one page worth of `file.txt` and output/write it to `output.txt.

Apparently, this does not work, `output.txt` is exactly the same as the original file, I'm wondering why this is the case, and if there are other work-arounds. Thank you!

Comment: The thing here is what do you call a page, 100 lines, 200?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I was assuming "one terminal full" of text, but clearly I wasn't thinking about that terminals can be resized. However, is there a way to specify how many lines to output?

Comment: yes, `sed -n '1,100p'` to print a hundred lines.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Thank you, could you show me the way you can use it with `less`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: jww is correct unfortunately, try to move your question the suggested forums. Anyway, there's a sequence of commands that can do what you want with less: 1) type `|` the prompt will change to `|mark: ` , 2) type `.` ( a dot) the prompt will change to `!`3) type `tee 1-page.txt` to write the current page to that file.

Comment: @yyin You wouldn't use `less` for this. You would just use sed/head directly on the file.

Comment: @that-other-guy I found the question interesting anyway as there's an answer using less. Think of the case where you are reading a file with less and want to save current page.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure the literal answer is what op is actually looking for

Comment: @that-other-guy can you move the question to one of the suggested forums?

Comment: I can only vote, but unless it turns out that this actually is a "how do I use `less`" question and not a "how do extract these lines in bash" question (which I'm guessing it is), it's on topic here

Comment: Here's the [question and answer on _Unix & Linux_ forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425804/how-to-save-current-page-to-file-in-less).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` command.

```
split -l 100 -d -a 3 input output
```

This will split the input file every 100 lines (-l 100), will use numbers as suffixes (-d) and will use 3 numbers as suffix (-a 3) in the output file. Something like this `output000, output001, output002`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `head` to get a specific number of lines, and `tput lines` to see how many lines there are on your current terminal.

Here's a script that fetches a pageful, or the standard 25 lines if no terminal is available:

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=$(tput lines) || lines=25
head -n "$lines" file.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

we use head and tail to get n lines of top or bottom part of a file

```
cat /var/log/messages|tail -n20 

head -n10 src/main.h
```

Comment: This prints multiple screens, if the lines are very long.